# How to Debug gcc code using cmake

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake

I have an c++ application developed using gcc(4.1) and compiled with CMAKE MakeFiles . The Code is large in size and debugging it is tough. I dont know how to debug the code line by line using cmake Utility. Any idea how to do it?

Thanks in advance :) .

Comment: cmake is not a debugger, use gdb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CMake is a system to enhance the definition of makefiles (it is a meta system that creates platform specific makefiles). It is not a debugger. You can use gdb for debugging.

To ensure your program is compiled for debugging properly, make sure the flags passed to gcc include `-O0`, which means no-optimizations, and `-g` for debugging information,
or `-ggdb` to produce a format that suits gdb really well (see also http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html).